# Newsletter for CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, newsletter

is there a newsletter code available for CI ?
Or something like PHPList for CI ?
Something that is already written in MVC and could be using CI mailing library?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter allows you to extend it by adding more libraries to it. You can actually put the **[PHPList Class(es)](http://www.phplist.com/)** in the `libraries` folder of CodeIgniter and modify it as per CI's documentation so that it works under CodeIgniter.

**[CI Resource on how to create/modify existing libraries.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)**

Comment: yes I could of course.
But is there anything written that is MVC?
or at least uses the CI mailing library?

Comment: @bhefny: MVC is part of CI, it handles anything put in the libraries folder unless you make or modify the class as per the requirement of CI, see my answer again for resource on CI how to create or extend CI with classes.

Comment: @Sarfraz. MVC is NOT a part of CI. CI follows the MVC pattern.

Comment: @Thorpe Obazee: I am fully aware of that, MVC is a design pattern that CI follows, it was just wording, thanks anyways. :)

Comment: hehe. I just thought that someone might interpret it wrong.

Comment: @Phil Sturgeon: it is not fight but even if it is, it is really good skill-building one, you learn a lot from comments :)

Comment: So... you back down from the fight? Thorpe wins! </humour>

Comment: "part of" or "follows" the question still stands.
I can either get a third party library like "PHPList" and run it with any MVC framework (like CI)
OR
someone has made a newsletter specially for CI, with CI functions, following/part of MVC, using CI libraries.
This is the question.

I proposed PHPList myself as I am currently using it in CI ;)